# ¿Cómo puedo calcular una columna en SQL-Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo una tabla que posee un valor diario fijo por mes y debe ir en una columna paralela sumando los valores de los días anteriores, como se ve en la imagen que adjunto que pude armar en excel, pero necesito hacer lo mismo en sql.

En la tabla con valores diarios y tabla con valores diarios acumulados, se puede observar la formula en la primera imagen y en la segunda como se van sumando los valores.

[image: imagen]

Comment: podrias agregar a tu pregunta la consulta

Comment: La tabla donde guardas el valor diario fijo tiene un campo fecha? De ser así podrías utilizar una subconsulta, compartenos la estructura de la misma para ayudarte mejor. Saludos

Comment: Qué versión de SQL Server estás usando?

Answer (score 1):

Una respuesta alterna si se usas SQL Server 2012 o superior:

```
SELECT Meta_Diaria, 
    SUM (Meta_Diaria) OVER (ORDER BY ID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS [Meta_Diaria_Acumulada]
FROM info.Tbl_Metas_mensuales
```

[Pruebalo en SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/28cce/9/0)

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una **solución genérica** a este problema, para que luego tu la adaptes:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.dayValues, SUM(t2.dayValues) AS SUM
FROM t t1
INNER JOIN t t2 ON t1.id >= t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.dayValues
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Puedes probarlo [Aquí en SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a2079)

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios Federico Madoery, tome tu idea y funciono perfectamente, muchas gracias, estaba hace un rato en eso.